# How to Mute the Sound of Application Alarm in watchOS?

Tags: objective-c, notifications, watchkit, alarm, watchos-2

I need to have the functionality to mute the notification sound in my watchOS 2 app using Objective-C.

How is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911627/detecting-cover-to-mute-action-on-apple-watch

Comment: @SeyyedParsaNeshaei So you mean it is not possible??

Comment: Not possible in watchOS 2, but maybe in watchOS 3. We should wait until WWDC16 (June 13) to see the new watchOS release. They may add this feature. Of course, you can submit this as an enhancement bug in Apple Developer Bug Reporting System (bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thank You @SeyyedParsaNeshaei .I have filed an enhancement bug.